# Preventing auto scale for 16-bit image data

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv, grayscale, 16-bit

When i try to save 16-bit image data in python, pixel values are automatically scaled to 65536. For example, max value in 16-bit data is 1536. If i saved and read this data, then max value becomes 65k. How to prevent this scaling? I tried different imaging library including opencv, PIL, misc, imageio , but all of these used this scaling.

For example:

```
img_arr # let it contains 16-bit gray-scale image data
print np.amax(img_arr) # it prints 1536
cv2.imwrite(img_arr, "asd.png")
img_arr = cv2.imread("asd.png")
print np.amax(img_arr) # it prints 65k value
```

Comment: try using other combos of the `imread` flags (optional second argument for `imread()`, see options [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80)). You can OR multiple flags together with `|`. Possibly helpful might be UNCHANGED, GRAYSCALE, and/or ANYDEPTH. Not sure if this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using **OpenCV**, this does what you seem to want.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Synthesize 200x200 uint16 image with 39,999 as max value
im = np.arange(0,40000,dtype=np.uint16).reshape((200,200))

# Write to disk
cv2.imwrite('result.png',im)

# Re-read from disk
rr = cv2.imread('result.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Check maximum value
print(rr.max())                # prints 39999
```

---

**PIL/Pillow** doesn't support 16-bit greyscale, so you'd need to promote to 32-bit signed, as so:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Synthesize 32-bit signed image
im = np.arange(0,40000,dtype=np.int32).reshape((200,200)) 

# Make into PIL Image
pim = Image.fromarray(im,'I')

# Save as 16-bit PNG, or 16-bit NetPBM PGM
pim.save('result.png')
pim.save('result.pgm')

# Re-read either file for same result, namely 39999
rr = np.array(Image.open('result.pgm')).max()
rr = np.array(Image.open('result.png')).max()
```